# ionic3 ion slides as stack cards effect

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Im using ionic . ion slides

```
<ion-slides pager>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: green">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: blue">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: red">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

i want something like this effect
i added

```
.swiper-slide{
position:absolute;
}
```

but no success . Actually i'm not getting any clue . how i to proceed with this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this question. There is a good guide here on how similar UI can be achieved by Simon: https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-tinder-cards/